# When are session cookies deleted by the browser?

Tags: asp.net, http, cookies, browser, session-cookies

If I set a cookie as a session cookie (no expires/max-age value), when does the browser remove the cookie?

I know that it is removed when the browser is closed but I'd like to know if there is ever a case where a session cookie can timeout or expire before the browser is closed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To quote [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1):

> If a cookie has neither the Max-Age nor the Expires
> attribute, the user agent will retain the cookie until "the current
> session is over" (as defined by the user agent).

And:

> The
> user agent is not required to retain the cookie for the specified
> duration.  In fact, user agents often evict cookies due to memory
> pressure or privacy concerns.

So: your mileage may vary.

Comment: Do the browser will physically remove the cookie, when they expire?

Comment: @murali what is "physically remove"? It depends entirely on the browser implementation. A browser may very well choose to save "session cookies" only in memory, for example.

Comment: I meant, will the browser delete it after expiry or it will leave as it is?

Comment: @Murali, I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: When cookie is marked invalid by the server, is cookie automatically deleted?